# Redirect response not shown with Swagger/Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle.Core with Asp.Net to return an IHttpActionResult for my API. The issue is the response in Swagger is returning a Response Code of 0, and Response body of no content but when I make the same call via postman the image I am redirecting to is returned and the Response code is 200 (which is the behavior I want).

Does swagger allow redirects like this? Is there a setting I am missing or any other suggestions on how to fix this?

The IHttpActionResult that I am returning:

```
public class ImageResponse : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private readonly string filePath;

        public LegacyImageResult(string filePath)
        {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

        private HttpResponseMessage Execute()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);

            try
            {
                if (filePath == null)
                {
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) { Content = new StringContent("Image not found.") };
                }
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(filePath);
            }
            catch
            {
                response.Dispose();
                throw;
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Edit:

Looks like this is a known Swagger issue
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/549